# Supported: histinfo in SIP INVITE

Tags: sip

I have a question regarding "Supported:histinfo" in incoming INVITE.
If the following example is a valid INVITE message? That is, it has "Supported:histinfo", but it actually uses Diversion header.
What does "Supported:histinfo" means? Only means the sender supports History-Info?

```
INVITE sip:7654321@xx.xx.xx.xx:5060 SIP/2.0
Supported: histinfo
Diversion: <sip:+12345678@1.2.3.4;user=phone>;reason=unconditional;counter=1
```

From RFC4244,

> A new Supported header, "histinfo", is included in the Request to
>   indicate whether the History-Info header is returned in Responses
>   (BACKWARDS-req).

So, seems that the above example is a valid one.

Thanks,
Ted

Comment: Diversion header was defined by RFC 5806 which is `Category: Historic`. `This document is not an Internet Standards Track specification; it is
   published for the historical record.` So the usage of the header Diversion is not standard. Any standard entity will just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for your info. But in the real world, a lot of entities support Diversion. Assume Diversion header is supported, if we receive the INVITE like the example, if it's a valid one? I mean if Diversion can be used here. Or, the incoming INVITE must use History-Info, since it has "Supported: info".

Comment: Supported is set by original sender - in this case any body redirecting request could add History-Info header `Whether the proxy supports the History-Info header.` + some other conditions. Somebody else has added Diversion header - so it is not supporting RFC4244 and supporting instead RFC5806. If you want to handle request based on RFC 4244 and add History-Info you just ignore Diversion header as there is no specification how its content could be translated to History-Info

Comment: I am actually wrong here - there is translation standard rfc6044

Comment: Yes, rfc6044 can be used for Diversion to History-Info translation. So, if a UA(support both Diversion and History-Info) receives such INVITE request, and wants to sent out INVITE using History-Info, it should use incoming INVITE Diversion header to convert to History-Info? I mean the sender can use Diversion header although it is saying it supports histinfo.

Comment: I'm not sure about sender - since Diversion was added by someone else. `When the Diversion header is used to create a History-Info header,
   the Diversion header must be removed in the outgoing INVITE.  It is
   considered that all of the information present in the Diversion
   header is transferred in the History-Info header.`  And another quote `When a proxy wants to interwork with a network supporting the other
   header field, it should apply the interworking between Diversion
   header and History-Info header in the 3xx response.`

Comment: So the recommended approach is `In a normal case, the network topology assumption is that the
      interworking described in this document should be performed by a
      specific SIP border device that is aware, by configuration, that
      it is at the border between two regions, one using History-Info
      header and one using Diversion header.`

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestion.